# Variables in PostgreSql (pgAdmnin query)

Tags: postgresql, variables

i have a query

```
delete from qdocs where path < './qbin/arch/2014-08-01' + and path > './qbin/arch'
```

need to make variable like

```
delete from qdocs where path < './qbin/arch/current_date - 31 day' + and path > './qbin/arch'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [date/time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html) like below:

```
delete from qdocs where path < './qbin/arch/' || current_date - 31 and path > './qbin/arch'
```

There are more possible ways to modify date:

```
select current_date - integer '31';
select (current_date - interval '31 days')::date;
select (current_date - interval '1 month')::date;
```